# Retrofit2 Authorization How to use Interceptor class for access token

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, retrofit2

I'm trying to get token when login then show a nickname in Main Activity.
But the nickname in Main activity is always null value.
I'm not sure how do I call from the Interceptor class to Main Activity.

- what I want to :
  [image]
- Current status :
  [image]
- BasicAuthInterceptor class :
  I try to connect this class and main class. But it didn't work.
  (when I did debug in main class, the nick name value is always null)

```
public class BasicAuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private String token;

    public BasicAuthInterceptor(String token){
        this.token = token;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        String token = UserPreference.getInstance().getString(Config.KEY_TOKEN);
        Request request = chain.request();
        Request authenticatedRequest = request.newBuilder()
                .header("authorization",token)
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(authenticatedRequest);
    }
```

- Retrofit class

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    public static RetrofitInterface buildHTTPClient() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("myurl")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(getClient())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
    }

   private static OkHttpClient getClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new BasicAuthInterceptor(Config.KEY_TOKEN))
                .build();
    }

    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor provideHttpLoggingInterceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(@NotNull String message) {
                Log.d("HTTP", message);
            }
        });
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        return httpLoggingInterceptor;
    }

    public static RetrofitInterface getRestMethods() {
        return buildHTTPClient();
    }
```

- RetrofitInterface interface : I cant add Header value when I get token in Main activity

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("v1/user/regist")
    Call<UserRegisterData> regist(@Field("email") String email, @Field("nickname") String nickname, @Field("password") String password);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("v1/user/login")
    Call<ApiResultDto> login(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);


   // @Header("key : authorization","token")

    @GET("v1/user/account")
    Call<UserAccountData> account(@Header("authorization") String token);
}
```

- Main Activity : after login to get token and user info

```
 public void initPreference() {
        userPreference = new UserPreference();
        userPreference.setContext(this);
    }

    public void userLogOut(View view) {
        userPreference.setLoggedIn(getApplicationContext(), false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        userLogOut(view);
    }

    private void getUser() {
         getToken = userPreference.getString(Config.KEY_TOKEN);
        RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = RetrofitClient.getRestMethods();
        Call<UserAccountData> call = retrofitInterface.account(getToken);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserAccountData>() {

            public void onResponse(Call<UserAccountData> call, Response<UserAccountData> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String nickName =response.body().getNickname();
                    getNickName.setText(nickName);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "token success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserAccountData> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "token fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the it to the okhttp client

```
 private static OkHttpClient getClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
               ---> .addInterceptor(BasicAuthInterceptor("YOUR TOKEN"))
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: I changed code what you said (Config.KEY_TOKEN). But It didnt work. When I debug " String nickName =response.body().getNickname();" in Main Activity.

Comment: you don't need `@Header("authorization") String token)` since you have `BasicAuthInterceptor`

Comment: If I delete "@GET("v1/user/account")
    Call<UserAccountData> account(@Header("authorization") String token);" in RetrofitInterface,                                                                                                         
 What should I write code here? " RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = RetrofitClient.getRestMethods();
        Call<UserAccountData> call = retrofitInterface.account(getToken); " in MainActivity